# React Composition and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

When applying CSS to a React document/app, is it more common to take elements out of the document flow (using things like position: relative) because they first tend to be grouped based on their data requirements?

Suppose Component A and Component B both depend on data returned from Component Z, but Component A and and Component B should render in different places on the page.  Is it very common in React to apply styles that alter the document flow?

Thanks

Comment: I would say that "no", that is not a common practice.  If you structure your app carefully, you shouldn't need to anything funky to get your styles in place.

Comment: I'm thinking about the Elements panel in development tools... paging down the DOM tree, read markup returned from Component A, page down to markup from Component B, and "it's way over there not even near Component A markup... repeated many times doesn't this get intuitive? But who writes React code thinking about style?

Comment: Why would they be in order like that?  You should have a DOM like any other.  You realize you are supposed to build your DOM by nesting components, right?

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name I would hope anyone who is writing presentational components would put a lot of thought into style. Your example of ComponentA, ComponentB isn't really a real work example. DOM is hierarchal in nature and so should your component structure be

Comment: @jmargolisvt In my case Components A and B have common props requirements provided by Component Z API call. To avoid that I either call twice, or make the React code less readable by passing the props way down...

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name if you provide a simple html `<header></header>` with a navigation, maybe a company brand img and some links + associated css - I will show you how to produce it in react so you see how it works.

Comment: Thanks @KyleRichardson  This doesn't really need such a detailed example.  API call 
Component Z returns a first name a last name and a nickname.  Component A should render first and last name top of the body. Other  components 123 not dependent on Z renders in the middle of the body after Component A. Finally, Component B, the nickname, which along with Component A has props passed down to it from Z, should render at the end of the body, after (123).  A and B are nested in Z.  123 are not.  Seems I have these options pass nickname props down, call the api twice, or hack the style